# Is it possible to build Windows 8 app using Windows 7 and Visual Studio 2012?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, windows-8, windows-7

Is it possible to build Windows 8 app using Windows 7 and Visual Studio 2012?

The app asks test questions. Two users answer by tapping on the screen, and they want to do it faster. I need to check who answered faster. I am not sure, maybe I should use multitouch staff here.

1. Is it possible to do it?
2. what is the best way of doing it?

Answer (score 0):

WinApp applications developed with the WinRT runtime can only work on systems windows8, if you develop applications with net framework, its work on Win7 and Win8.

To make the application can use WinRT or net framework, you simply need to touch screens ... however you can assess who presses the button first with the classic mouse click.

Only if you install VS2012 on Win8 can develop WinApp, however for what you want to do I would use a Windows Application developed with VS2012.